# Finding sockaddr info before reading udp

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Is there anyway that I can get the sockaddr information from an incoming packet without actually doing a recvfrom on the data first? I was just wondering cause you can tell that there is something to be read with like a poll or select I was wondering if I can pull more information from this before actually reading the data that was sent. I ask this because I have a system where each individual ip/port combination has its own little internal buffer that we put chunked messages into and I need to know so that I can put it in the right internal buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by supplying the MSG_PEEK flag to the [`recvfrom`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvfrom.html) call.

```
recvfrom(socket, buffer, 1, MSG_PEEK, &address, &address_len);
```

This will leave the datagram intact and not remove it. You can of course specify a smaller value for the buffer size to reduce unecessary read overhead. The next time you do a normal `recvfrom` the datagram will be removed as normal.

```
recvfrom(socket, buffer, length, 0, &address, &address_len); // Do the actual read
```

Comment: If I have packets from multiple sources waiting to be received will they stay in order? In other words if I do a peek and get the sockaddr information am I guaranteed that the next call to recvfrom to actually get the info will be the same source? If not is there anyway to force a recv from a specific sockaddr manually?

Comment: Yes. the packets will remain in order. All the flag does is allow you to examine the datagram without removing it from or reordering it in the queue.